ssis how to replace blank values with null or a fake date value
I am trying to import data from a text file, however there are couple columns that represents date as yyyymmdd. In trying to convert to date format yyyy-mm-dd I've used the following in a derive column:
(DT_WSTR)[PROCESSED_DT]== "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR) : PROCESSED_DT == (DT_WSTR,8)00000000 ? (DT_WSTR,4)LEFT(PROCESSED_DT,4) + "-" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING(PROCESSED_DT,5,2) + "-" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING(PROCESSED_DT,7,2)
but getting the results as:
enter image description here
sample of source data:
Source Column   Derived result
20220101    2022-01-01
20220203    2022-02-03
20240401    2024-04-01
1901-01-01
20240501    2024-05-01

First the format of the data should not be done on the database level (as long as it is a valid date) then import it.  Let any UI layer format it the way you need.

Second doing this type of work is possible as you are looking at but I find when importing data from files (or even other external databases) it is easier to import into a staging table firsts (may all be text/varchar columns) then have an SP take the data from the stage table into the main table you are trying to import to and on that import do all the data cleanup, transforms, and any additional logic required, before importing into the main table.  It makes it much easier to account for data transforms and validation.

thx, the data is being transformed using a derived column in ssis. I was able to have it tweak it to have it working ...
